# Unrestricted free tool for finding 404's?

Tags: analytics, 404, tools

Google WebMaster Tools limit to the first 1000 (I won't get into that), Xenu doesn't seem to list the page the offending link is on, and W3C limits to the first 150 pages.

Can someone suggest a tool (preferably free) that will spider through an entire website and kick out the 404's as well as the page each 404 is on?

Comment: The mechanic may vary, what you want is a tool that just triggers random page requests to see if you get a 404 or you want a tool that traverses a site and reports broken links?

Comment: Reporting on broken links on our site, and preferably 404's for others linking to our content that has been decommissioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xenu does report pages linking to the 404. Right click the error URL in the report, select URL Properties. You can do a report, too, (File > Report) which will list broken links by page they occur on.

Comment: I did try to run the Xenu report, but the page on which the link is found on doesn't seem to be listed anywhere.  I did look at the preferences, but don't see anything that looks equivalent to Google's "Linked from" field.

Comment: I'm not sure which option I changed in pref's, but I am looking closely at a new report I generated and do see what I'm looking for.  Thanks!